# Post sending base64 encoded image through curl

Tags: php, curl, upload

I am trying to send a base64 image through curl as a file. I tried doing it using curl_file_create but I am pretty sure you can't do it this way.

Could anyone help me send a base64 png image through curl without needing to upload it to my server?

Doing the following code, I get a `$http_response == 0`

```
    $data = BASE64 IMAGE DATA;
    //$args['file'] = curl_file_create($data, 'image/png', 'signature');
    $args['file'] = new CurlFile($data, 'image/png', 'signature');

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.website.com/docs',
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => "123",
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data"),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $args
    ));
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    $http_status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($curl);

    echo $resp."<br /><br />".$http_status;
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I would like to base64-encode a file before sending it. Preferably without having to store a temp-file to the drive.

Comment: I solved this issue by storing the base64 image with a unique name using amazon s3 and then storing the name in my database. It works really nicely and is very cost effective. I know this may not work for your workflow but let me know if you need help implementing and I'll be happy to post my solution.